# Запретить установку и удаление плагинов второму администратору

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим в админке wordpress зарегистрированы 2 администратора, второй администратор нужен для теста сайта и отладки, потому-что будут участвовать несколько человек в тестах.
Подскажите, как можно в wordpress ограничить некоторые возможности 2го администратора, чтобы допустим запретить ему установку плагинов, или удаление плагинов? И на какой это хук цепляется, чтобы ограничить права?

Попробовал сделать самостоятельно, но это ограничение не срабатывает:

```
function wpcodex_set_capabilities() {

    // Перечень прав на удаление
    $caps = array(
        'install_plugins'
    );

    $user_id = 2; // ID администратора, которго надо ограничить в правах
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {
        // Удалить права
        $user->remove_cap( $cap );
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_set_capabilities' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для запрета установки плагинов и редактирования файлов плагинов и темы нужно добавить следующие строки в config.php:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

Если у второго админа нет доступа к ftp, он не сможет выполнять перечисленные действия. Да и никто не сможет.

**UPDATE:**

Есть возможности отнять некоторые capabilities (права) у определенного администратора:

```
function wpcodex_set_capabilities() {

    // Перечень прав на удаление
    $caps = array(
        'activate_plugins',
        'export',
        'remove_users',
        'switch_themes',
        'delete_site'
    );

    $user_id = xxx; // ID администратора, которго надо ограничить в правах
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {     
        // Удалить права
        $user->remove_cap( $cap );
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_set_capabilities' );
```

Полный перечень ролей и прав можно посмотреть в [кодексе](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).